# How to generate unique integer values in Java (Android) at compile time

Tags: java, android

I need lots of unique integers in my Android code, for example for intent request codes.

I don't want to have to worry about collisions, even if I move fragments between activities. So I want them to be globally unique.

At the moment, I am doing this manually.

```
    public static final int HTTP_ADD_OR_REMOVE_CALENDAR_REQUEST_CODE = 20001;
```

This is annoying and error prone.
Is there a way to tell Android/Java:

"I want a unique integer here, please set it at compile time" ?

Of course I'd rather use an enum, but apparently that's not the Android way...

Comment: Java has no concept like Go's [`iota`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Iota). So... I think there is no way to fixate the values at compile time automatically. What we could do is create a `static int counter = 0` and then always set `public static final int MY_VALUE = counter++;`. This, however, may not guarantee that the values are always the same if `counter` is used across multiple classes.

Comment: You could use `new Random().nextInt(0, 400000)` the odds of collision are low :-)

Comment: or write a class that generates ints, then save them in a pool (to avoid collisions) then request one from the pool instead of generating one.

Comment: @Blundell both approaches will not guarantee that the values are always the same.

Comment: You could also come up with a schema and use bit shifting to generate codes. i.e. use a major number for the name of the fragment and a minor number. That way you wouldn't get collisions even when moved.

Comment: @Turing85 the pool would be passed a unique key :-)

Comment: What makes you think you need a unique integer value for intent request codes?

Comment: "I want a unique integer here, please set it at compile time" -- use [an ID resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id). However, I agree with Ian: there should be few places in an app where you need a process-wide unique ID.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think your comment answers the question ... and yes, I shouldn't need a process-wide unique ID, but even defining unique IDs for, say, the http requests of an activity is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: I have the RequestCodes class. I am creating request code for all activities starting from 1 here. so it is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [ID resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id) will give you an integer that does not collide with any other ID resources used in your app (e.g., for widget IDs in a layout resource).

Answer (score 1):

Create an enum.  Then you just add a new item to the enum.

You don't want to assign these at compile time.  Half the point of these ids is to make it easy when using a debugger to be able to tell what the id is and figure out what the matching constant is.  Assigning at compile time makes that a nightmare.  It will cost you a TON of time in maintenance down the line.  You'd be trading seconds at time of writing for hours of time in maintenance.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because I think it adds a valuable insight, but I accepted the other one because it more directly answers the question. (Even if the question is mis-guided). I hope that makes sense.